# topgo lapply instead of for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply, sapply

I'm new to R. How can I write this in `apply`/`sapply` instead of a `for` loop?

```
for ii in c(1:5) {
     resultFisher <- runTest(sampleGOdata, algorithm = "classic", statistic = "fisher")
}
```

I tried

```
lapply(1:5, function(X) resultFisher <- runTest(sampleGOdata, algorithm = "classic", statistic = "fisher"))
```

and it didn't work, it just runs it over and over again but doesn't actually loop through it.

Thanks!!

Comment: In both loops, you do not use the iterator variable (`ii` and `X`).  Unless `runTest` does some randomized process, all outputs should be the same. Also, you do not assign `lapply` to anything. Likely you meant to use `resultFisher <- lapply(...)`.

Comment: But you need to tell us (and R) what changes each time. Do you want to run `runTest` on each column of data? Each row? Something else? Even your `for` loop just "runs it over and over again".